# Multiple if/else statements vs foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm just trying to figure out which would be better, in the long term, as well as if there is a performance difference between these two scenarios.

We're maintaining a site we did *not* create, and we're trying to add something dynamically to the sidebar on certain pages, and trying to decide if there's a reason to use a foreach loop or multiple if/else statements.

We're going to end up with *a lot* more pages than the 6 shown here, so performance could be considered a concern.

The foreach loop looks like this:

```
$rb_enabled = false;

$RURLs = array(
    '/cambridge.php' => 'cambridge',
    '/milton.php' => 'milton',
    '/kitchener_waterloo.php' => 'kw',
    '/hamilton_dundas.php' => 'hd',
    '/oakville.php' => 'oakville',
    '/brantford.php' => 'brantford'
);

foreach( $RURLs as $rurl => $engine_location ){
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $ru){
        $rb_url == $engine_location;
        $rb_enabled == true;
    } 
}

if($rb_enabled === true){ //create a div with information based on engine location }
```

The sidebar php file this gets loaded into is on many pages, some of which need this div created specifically for it, other pages need to not have it at all, hence the `$rb_enabled`.

Is there a reason that foreach loop is better or worse than this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/cambridge.php'){ $rb_url = 'cambridge'; $rb_enabled = true; }
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/milton.php'){ $rb_url = 'milton'; $rb_enabled = true; }
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/kitchener_waterloo.php'){ $rb_url = 'kw'; $rb_enabled = true; }
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/hamilton_dundas.php'){ $rb_url = 'hd'; $rb_enabled = true; }
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/oakville.php'){ $rb_url = 'oakville'; $rb_enabled = true; }
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/brantford.php'){ $rb_url = 'brantford'; $rb_enabled = true; }
```

The if statements are a bit redundant with the `$rb_enabled`, but wondering if there's any reason to use one way over the other, even if it's only "which code you would rather take over if you were the next one with hands on this project" if that's the only reason.

Also open to a new idea entirely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have an array with the URI's as key, so why not use `array_key_exists()`?

```
if(array_key_exists($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $RURLS)) {
    $rb_enabled = true;
    $rb_url = $RURLS[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];
}
```

There is no need to loop through the array, or provide multiple if or switch/case statements. The performance for this lookup will not degrade as the size of your URI array increases (well within reason at least - if you have a huge array that takes up lots of memory, that could be a problem.)

Comment: I believe the end array will be well within reason, so I'm going to go ahead and use this. Thanks, and accepted!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `switch/case` syntax for what you asking for:

```
switch( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) {
    case '/milton.php':
       $rb_url = 'milton';
       $rb_enabled = true;
       break;

    ....
}
```

Comment: I would only favor an if/switch for a case like this for a *fixed set* when there is *not* a well-defined heuristic/map that can be applied. (And if there are only a few special cases - i.e. performing an additional action - I would handle them separately.)

Comment: I had considered this, but it's more code than the if/else statements, and it still has to cycle through them. While not a bad suggestion, it's roughly on par with the if/else. +1 for the though, but I'm going to recommend anyone else how comes across this to use [array_key_exists()](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) :)

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
list($rb_enabled,$rb_url) = ($url=$RURLs[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']])? array(true,$url) : null ;
```